Canvas content escapes canvas on mobile in Firefox
I am scaling (and translating) an HTML canvas via its CSS transform attribute. This works as expected in most environments, however, in Firefox on a mobile device (Android 14) the content does not fit its canvas towards the bottom right corner. By content I mean something drawn to the canvas using e.g. either ctx.fillRect(...) or ctx.putImageData(...). This mismatch can be seen by giving the canvas a background color (pink in the example) and drawing to it using ctx.fillRect(...) or ctx.putImageData(...) (grey in the example). This Codepen directly showcases the problem (the checkerboard highlights individual canvas pixels). The code below also showcases the problem but does not highlight the canvas pixels (it still shows the mismatch) in order to be more concise.
Note that the canvas's content always perfectly fits the canvas in the top left corner. By that I mean that in the top left corner of the canvas, i.e. at (0,0) in canvas coordinates, there is no visible mismatch / offset. This suggests that the content is aligned properly to the top left corner and it's its dimensions (width, height) which do not match those of the canvas.
I have briefly tested this in Firefox, Edge, Chrome and Opera on both desktop and mobile and the problem occurs solely in Firefox on mobile.
The mismatch in Firefox on mobile
The mismatch in Firefox on mobile with highlighted canvas element
Expected
Expected with highlighted canvas element
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canv"></canvas>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </body>
</html>

main.js:
const canvas = document.getElementById('canv')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5)`
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

style.css:
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#canv {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    transform: translate(-14800px, -7000px) scale(100);
}

Among other things I suspected this to have something to do with fractional scaling or translations, but in this minimal example there are no fractions involved, it's all integer values. The codepen demonstrates that it's not about too many or too few individual canvas pixels being drawn, as the mismatch is smaller than the dimensions of a canvas pixel. In case this might be relevant, the device I used has a devicePixelRatio of 2.608695652173913.
At this point I have been scratching my head about this for a while and am not sure what else to look into. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
